# Counting letter frequency bug

Tags: java

I'm creating a program that reads in txt files and counts the frequency of symbols/letters/numbers. So far, I have used a HashMap to store these values and print them to the screen (in alphabetical order).

I have managed to print the keys in ascending order however I am getting a ' : 1' at the start of the list, I can't seem to figure out where I've gone wrong.

```
public class abc {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\random20000.txt"));
    HashMap<Character, Integer> hmap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    String s = reader.readLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i ++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        Integer val = hmap.get(new Character(c));
        if (val != null && c != ' ') {
            hmap.put(c,  new Integer(val + 1));
        }
        else {
            hmap.put(c, 1);
        }

    }
    reader.close();



    System.out.println("Hash Map Before Sorting");
    Set set = hmap.entrySet();
    Iterator iterator = set.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry<Character, Integer> me = (Map.Entry<Character, Integer>)iterator.next();
        System.out.print(me.getKey() + ": ");
        System.out.println(me.getValue());
    }
```

I have a feeling it's either the (val != null && c != ' ') or the hmap.put(c,1) line.

Comment: Are there any other white space characters in your text file like newline and tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Integer val = hmap.get(new Character(c));
if (val != null && c != ' ') {
    hmap.put(c,  new Integer(val + 1));
}
else {
    hmap.put(c, 1);
}
```

Here you are only checking if it is a space when you are *updating* the number. So the first time a space is found, it's inserted in the map. So you need to check that it's not a space in both cases.

For instance something like

```
if (c != ' ') {
    Integer val = hmap.get(new Character(c));
    if (val != null) {
        hmap.put(c,  new Integer(val + 1));
    }
    else {
        hmap.put(c, 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, it's every time a space is found ... it just writes `1` over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in my opinion is problem with your datafile. I have same result as you if there is " " space character in this file. Please post your datafile.